# Excel VBA - Select a dynamic cell range excluding headers

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to analyze huge amount of data in a spreadsheet. The records are being added,removed all the time. My headers are on the first rows, which I don't want to select. What I want to do is to select cells specifically starting from the cell B2, all the to the end of the records dynamically, both column wise and row wise. In other words select only the data records starting from the cell B2.

The code I've been trying to implement as follows so far:

```
Range(Cells(B2, Rows.Count).End(xlToLeft), Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).Select
```

which doesn't work. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Is there data in colA ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your range is continuous you could try to do it this way:

```
Range("B2", range("B2").end(xlToRight).End(xlDown)).select
```

By the way, there could be plenty of other solutions with similar result. I've tried to do it as short as possible (based on information provided in question).

Comment: Thanks for the reply KazJaw. But it doesn't select the whole thing column wise.

Comment: I would need to see the structure of your data/table to give more accurate help. Could you upload a screen shot or document somewhere in internet and give a link here?

Comment: Using `.end(xlToRight)` or the like runs the risk of running into empty cells.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few ways to do this. I find I use different approaches based on the structure of the data. 
One way is:

```
activesheet.range("B2:" &  Activesheet.cells(2,2).specialcells(xlcelltypelastcell).address).select
```

You can either use the range address as I did above or you can supply the end and start cells as in: 
    With ActiveSheet
        .Range(.Cells(2, 2), .Cells(.UsedRange.Rows.Count, .UsedRange.Columns.Count)).Select
    End With

Also, for reference, there are options such as intersect and union that can be useful: 
    With ActiveSheet
        Application.Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Rows("2:1048576")).Select
    End With

It goes on and on. I think the first example will most likely get you out of trouble...